# jQuery Mobile: Initializing external toolbar has confusing syntax

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

[On this page](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/toolbar-fixed-external/), it's indicated that to use fixed external toolbars you need to initialize the toolbar manually since it's not within the normal page cycle.

The example code is here:

```
$(function(){
  $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
});
```

I don't understand the code is wrapped in a function like that? It's putting an anonymous function inside the the jQuery `$` function, where selectors would normally go.

Can anyone explain the methodology of that anonymous function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(function(){` is shorthand for `$( document ).ready(function() {`

> **[DOCUMENTATION](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**
>
> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

So once jQuery is ready, it will initialize the external toolbars once.

Comment: Thanks, did not know of the shorthand.